# Cannot be authenticated on two separared CakePHP applications on same server

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have two different CakePHP based applications on same server. They are placed in separated directories, and each of them use it's own database. Also, they both have implemented authentication. So, (in my opinion) they are fully independent.

Problem I have is that I cannot be logged-in in same time in both applications (in same browser).

Can you help me what I'm doing wrong in this case, and how can I be authenticated in both of them sametime?

Comment: how you are saving your session data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change Session.save variable in app/config/core.php. Default is 'php', so change it to 'cake'. This  will make Cakephp store the Session variables in the app/tmp/sessions directory. Remember to give write permissions to this folder. Also make shure that both apps have diffrent Security.salt key in the same config file.